# apache mod_wsgi error, randomly: Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

Recently, our server shut down out of nowhere, this what Apache logs show up:

`[wsgi:error] [pid 8837:tid 140646648096512] (2)No such file or directory: [client] mod_wsgi (pid=8837): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'project' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.22155.8.1.sock' as user with uid=33., referer: http://project.com/login/`

I fixed it by running a `sudo service apache2 restart` and everything is back to normal but, Should I be worried about this? This happened like a year ago and I did the same thing.

Comment: did you already have a look at the wscgi log? mostly maybe you can and moreover have to dump all information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it